# Is there a way to remove this feature on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently whenever I am coding specifically in Java and have a line of code like sysout, I keep getting the data type or variable before the actual code. Unable to backspace it as it seems to be an overlay without doing anything to the code. I've never had this picky issue before and am unsure if its been implented through vs code or its an extension I have. If anyone knows how I could get rid of the "x: " in line 4 of the image below then that would be great.

Thank you

[Line 4 of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSJh5.png)

Comment: This is a hint of the parameter name, without any actual effect. Also present in IntelliJ IDEA. Informative for methods with multiple parameters, i.e. especially for booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new vscode feature and has nothing to do with Java or any extensions. To get rid of it, put the following in your `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.inlayHints.enabled": false
```

To open your settings.json, open the command palette and search for “settings” and click on `Open user settings (JSON)`.